# Не работает второе die()

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, sql-server, веб-сервер

Всем привет,не могу разобраться в чём проблема

```
mysql_connect("localhost","id2134350_egor","26718323aA")

or die ("<p>Error sql connection: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");

echo "Connection ok";

mysql_select_db("id2134350_greendale")
or die ("Error database selected: " . mysql_error() . );

echo "Database selected";
```

Второе `die` не работает, а `echo` выбивает всегда тру, хоть и нейм бд не верный.

Инструкция `die` пропускается что-ль.

Php 5.4

Comment: Вижу ошибку в синтаксисе `die ("Error database selected: " . mysql_error() . );` - последняя точка лишняя

Comment: Спасибо что заметили , увы проблема именно в die. Точку оставил случайно при редактировании кода, там после точки еще просто идет текст.

Comment: в php.ini параметр sql.safe_mode как настроен?

Comment: Никак,в кратце я нью мен в этом деле.Купил учебники,начал тестировать на практике,нашёл хостинг.Закидую туда и проверяю,до этого было всё в порядке х( Вроде как проблем то и не должно быть,но не пойму почему пропускает инструкцию.Мей би хост кривой ?

Comment: не в тему: Вам, как родному, советую продать этот учебник и купить по mysqli и PDO

Comment: Кстати - а первый ДАЙ срабатывает, проверяли?

Comment: Кхм,прислушаюсь , я за этим сюда и пришёл вообщем то ! ) А в чём плюсы если не секрет , и если не буду слишком навязчив ?

Comment: В этом и проблема,первый Die работает , второй нет.

Answer (score -1):

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","id2134350_egor","26718323aA");

if (!$link) {
die('Не удалось соединиться : ' . mysql_error());
}

// выбираем "id2134350_greendale" в качестве текущей базы данных

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("id2134350_greendale", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Не удалось выбрать базу "id2134350_greendale": ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: в чем отличие твоего кода, от кода в вопросе? почему ты думаешь, что твое решение работает, в отличие от примера автора вопроса?

Comment: Верно,нечего не изменилось х( Аналогично ошибка с 1 инструкции выходит на ура , при специальном допущении ошибки ко второй инструкции реакции 0.

Comment: Найди два отличия:
[https://prnt.sc/fwmp3g]

Comment: Интересно,но у меня не работает.Значит проблема в чём то другом ?